# Exporting from SQL Server into CSV files with ISO-8859-15 encoding

Tags: sql-server, csv, powershell

I am trying to export a SQL Server database into CSV files. For that, I am using a powershell script.

As you can see, in the database I have some special characters (Danish language).

[image: capture of my database table]

But in the exported files, those characters are replaced with a ? as you can see below :

[image: csv output file]

For information, in my powershell script, here is the line exporting the file :

$DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding "ISO-8859-15"

Can anyone help? Thanks!

EDIT :

@JamesQMurphy here is the code

[image: dataset]

Comment: Is -Encoding "ISO-8859-15" a valid encoding parameter? I thought the list was Unicode, UTF7, UTF8, ASCII, UTF32, BigEndianUnicode, Default, and OEM? Have you tried -Encoding UTF7 for example?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you show the code that populates your $DataSet?

Comment: I edited my post. You can now see the code. @JamesQMurphy

Answer (score 2):

Tested this and the correct encoding for me was BigEndianUnicode

Change your encoding to this:

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding BigEndianUnicode
```

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, then I have to echo @JamesQMurphy...can you show the code that populates your $DataSet?